# Is this cardinality many-to-many or many-to-one?

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, many-to-one

I'm about to setup a bunch of databases but I'm stuck at the moment.

There is a table of multible schools [**school**] that teach subjects [**subject**].
Each school teaches one subject or more than one subject. The subjects don't know about the schools.

I thought I could implement a table like "[**school_teaches_subject**]" that holds a school_ID and a subject_ID. That way I can see the subjects of a school by reading the school_ID for example.

In this case, is the relationship between school and subject one-to-many or many-to-many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a subject can appear multiple times in your intersection table it's M-M, if only once (i.e. a subject can only ever be taught at one school) then's it's 1-M.  Decide what you need it to be and set your constraints accordingly.